# Check if a rtmp-stream is running and start ffmpeg with PHP / Shell-Script / Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, shell, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to transcode a rtmp-stream and re-stream it with ffmpeg.

I have 2 problems:

- how can I check if the remote rtmp-stream is running and then start ffmpeg
- sometimes ffmpeg brake up transcoding and it must be restartet automatically

Any hints to do this with a shell-script, ruby or php?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+rmtp&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "GOD" for my solution:

http://god.rubyforge.org/

Comment: give me some example for the god to do this task